# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.OwnerId

Tags: apex, soql, controller-extension, redirect

I have the following code:

```
public with sharing class ExportCheckPageController {

public boolean checkYes {
    get{if(checkYes == null)
        checkYes = false;
        return checkYes;}
    set;}
public boolean checkNo{
    get{if(checkNo == null)
        checkNo = false;
        return checkNo;}
    set;}
/*public boolean q1{
  get{if(q1 == null)
  q1 = false;
  return q1;}
  set;} */ 

public Export_Check__c exportCheck {get; set;}
public Opportunity opp {get;set;}
private account acc;
private Id sgiRT;
private Id apacRT;
private Id oppId;
private List<Export_Check__c> exportList = new List<Export_Check__c>();
private List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
private ApexPages.standardController controller;

public ExportCheckPageController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    controller = stdController;
    exportCheck = new Export_Check__c();
    opp = new Opportunity();
    acc = new Account();
    opp =(Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    oppId =stdController.getid();
    system.debug(oppId);

    if((ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId') != null) && (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId') != '')){
        oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
        system.debug(oppId);
    }
    sgiRT = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SGI Opportunity'].Id;
    //apacRT = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SGI APAC Opportunity'].Id;
    loadOppExports();
    system.debug(oppId);
}

public void loadOppExports(){
    if(oppId != null){
        //Add all other fields from opportunity i may need & from Opp Account
        //Gonna have to do a few more quries to get all info from acount and contacts
        opp = [Select Id, Name, Account.Id, isExportCompleted__c, (Select Id, Name, ExportStatus__c, CheckNO__c, CheckYes__c, OppExportCheck__c from Export_Checks__r) From Opportunity where id =: oppId];
        acc = [select Id, Owner.Id, Parent.Id, Parent.Name, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, 
               Street_Address__c, City__c, State_Province__c, Zip_Postal_Code__c, Country_Code__c, Account_Intergraph_Line_of_Business__c, Industry, Type, 
               Phone, Account_Category__c, RecordTypeId,(select Id, account.id, Name, firstname, lastname, account.name, Account_Industry__c, Department, 
                                                         MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingState, MailingCountry, Email, Phone from contacts) 
               from Account where account.id in (Select Opportunity.AccountId From Opportunity where id =: opp.id)];
        system.debug(opp);
        system.debug(acc);
        //Check List size - but there should only be one- maybe need to revisit this later
        if(!opp.Export_Checks__r.isEmpty()){
            for(Export_Check__c ec: opp.Export_Checks__r){
                if(ec.Id != null){
                    //exportCheck = new Export_Check__c();
                    exportCheck = ec;
                    exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c = ec.OppExportCheck__c;
                    system.debug(exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c);
                }
                else{
                    //exportCheck = new Export_Check__c();
                    exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c = opp.Id;
                    system.debug(exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //exportCheck = new Export_Check__c();
            exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c = opp.Id;
            system.debug(exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c);
        }
    }
}

public PageReference redirect(){
    PageReference pr;
    if(opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT ){
        if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null){
            pr = new PageReference('/apex/ExportCheckPage1?oppId='+ opp.Id);
            pr.setRedirect(true); 
        }
    }
    else{
        pr = new PageReference('/' + opp.id);
        pr.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    }
    return pr;
}     

public void setExportCheck(){
    if(checkYes){
        opp.isExportCompleted__c = false;
        exportCheck.Name = opp.Name;
        exportCheck.Company_Name__c = acc.Name;
        exportCheck.Country__c = acc.Country_Code__c;
        exportCheck.City__c = acc.City__c; 
        exportCheck.State__c = acc.State_Province__c;
        exportCheck.Street_1__c = acc.Street_Address__c;
        exportCheck.Zip__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code__c;
        exportCheck.CheckYes__c = checkYes;
        exportCheck.CheckNO__c = checkNo;
        exportCheck.ExportStatus__c = 'Under Review';
        //eventually we will want to set all of Export Yes/No questions here

    }
    else if(checkNo){
        opp.isExportCompleted__c = true;
        exportCheck.Name = opp.Name;
        exportCheck.Company_Name__c = acc.Name;
        exportCheck.Country__c = acc.Country_Code__c;
        exportCheck.City__c = acc.City__c; 
        exportCheck.State__c = acc.State_Province__c;
        exportCheck.Street_1__c = acc.Street_Address__c;
        exportCheck.Zip__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code__c;
        exportCheck.CheckNO__c = checkNo;
        exportCheck.CheckYes__c = checkYes;
        exportCheck.Export1__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export2__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export3__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export4__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export5__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export6__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.Export7__c = 'No';
        exportCheck.ExportStatus__c = 'Approved';

    }
    else{
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'You must select one of the Yes or No options below. '));
    }
    if(!exportList.isEmpty()){
        exportList.clear();
        exportList.add(exportCheck);
        system.debug(checkNo);
        system.debug(checkYes);
        system.debug(exportCheck);
        system.debug(opp);

    }
    else{
        exportList.add(exportCheck);
        system.debug(checkNo);
        system.debug(checkYes);
        system.debug(exportCheck);
        system.debug(opp);

    }
}
public PageReference startApproval(){
    //This method will start he approval process - Do an insert of an record and kick off the approval process.
    //Phase 1 - Start he approval process, display info messages on page to tell the user what the next steps to take
    //Phase 2 - Add Steps for the rest of the attachments to be completed in Salesforce and then send to Compliance team for approval
    //Phase 3 - Do a web service call out to Tradebeam to do export screening and and store this informationon the object. 
    Database.SaveResult[] insertEx;
    system.debug(exportList);
    system.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
    system.debug(Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
    insertEx = database.insert(exportList, false);
    for (Database.SaveResult sr: insertEx){
        if(sr.isSuccess()){
            system.debug('Insert Succeeded. Export ID: '+ sr.getId());
        }
        else{
            for(database.Error err: sr.getErrors()){
                system.debug('The following error has occured. ');
                system.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                system.debug('Error fields: ' + err.getFields());

            }
        }
    }
    try{
        system.debug(opp);
        update opp;
    }
    catch(DMLException ex){
        system.debug('Error+++ '+ ex);
    }

    PageReference redirect =  new PageReference('/apex/StandardOpportunity?id='+ opp.Id);
    redirect.setRedirect(true);
    return redirect;
    //return Page.StandardOpportunity;
}
}
```

and the requirements changed to add this line of code`((opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT) && opp.OwnerId == UserInfo.getUserId() )` in the Redirect method and replace `if(opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT )` but now I get the error of:  SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.OwnerId

As you can see I am querying Opportunity.OwnerId in the SOQL query and I have the field listed in my VF page. I'm confused to why it is erroring out.

Comment: First you are not quering `OwnerId`. And second I can't see you are using `opp.OwnerId` in any of your code.. Can you pls let us know in which line you are getting error?

Comment: Are you getting a trigger error?

Comment: the error is coming from this line         'if ((opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT) && opp.OwnerId == UserInfo.getUserId() )'

Comment: @AdrianLarson not sure by what you mean with a trigger error?

Comment: @user3708392 That line does not appear in your code in the OP so your question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson you're right, but if you read what I wrote below where the requirements changed it produced the error. :) I fixed the error now, but now it won't redirect correctly like it used to, to the ExportCheckPage1 :-/ it goes straight to the opportunity detail page for some reason?

Comment: You can consult your `redirect` method for why that is and cross reference it with the data you're working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a `StandardController`, there are a few different ways to manipulate the way it queries for the record. Note your line in the constructor:

```
 opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
```

The above performs a query, pulling down all fields used on the page. In addition to what fields you use on the page, you can use the `addFields` method (though it cannot be used in a test).

```
List<String> fieldsToQuery = new List<String> { 'OwnerId' };
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(fieldsToQuery);
// getRecord
```

Another option is to actually include them on the page through various forms of dummy markup. One example:

```
<apex:variable var="ownerId" value="{!Opportunity.OwnerId}" />
```

As for the query in your `startApproval` method, since you already have your `Opportunity` data, it is probably more straightforward to query for the child data directly instead of overwriting your saved `opp`.

```
List<Export_Check__c> childExportChecks = [SELECT ... FROM Export_Check__c];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Adrian Larson! I'm now getting an error to check and make sure an Id is null, on this like 'if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null) '. It's saying I'm trying to Attempt to de-reference a null object. How would I go about making sure an Id is null?

Comment: Do you have a `null` value in `exportCheck`? The record itself has to be initialized before you can check the value of its Id.

Comment: it is null. How would I initialize it?

Comment: I think you need to ask a separate question around that. *It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.* You could pull it from a query, or you could create one like `exportCheck = new Export_Check__c()`.

Comment: I assume I need to do that in the redirect method? I have this if statement that is instantiating it '       if(!opp.Export_Checks__r.isEmpty()){ 
          exportCheck = opp.Export_Checks__r[0]; 
      }
      else{
          exportCheck = new Export_Check__c();
          exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c = opp.Id;
          system.debug(exportCheck.OppExportCheck__c);'

Comment: That's really out of scope compared to your original question. If you must further discuss, please do so [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/34980/discussion-between-adrian-and-user3708392?tab=general). I would advise asking a separate question.

Comment: I'll meet you there!