# Building custom VF approval page Query Issues

Tags: visualforce, soql, query, approval-process, relationships

Some questions on displaying on what I can show in querying the Process.

1 - I am running into limitations on pulling in more fields in my query.

```
public List<ProcessInstanceStep> getSteps() {
      return [select StepStatus,  ProcessInstance.targetObject.name from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :T.id ];
    }
```

The above successfully returns the name of the object under approval, but that isn't that helpful, since it's an auto number.

Trying to pull any other field provides errors. Example:

```
return [select StepStatus,  ProcessInstance.targetObject.Field__C from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :T.id ];
```

Brings error:

> No such column 'Field__c' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.

Why is it referencing entity Name ? Have I reached the limit in relation query? thanks

2. I am having a error trying to query on a field on the initial object

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Custom_Object__c.Look_up__c

I want to query on an ID in a lookup field on the object.
The below does not allow me to query on a custom field on T but I think illustrates what I want to do:

```
    Custom_Object__c T;
    public ID TID {get; set; }
    public TravelerApprovalExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

         T = (Custom_object__C) controller.getRecord(); 
         TID = t.Look_up__c;
    }
```

So I can use TID here:

```
public List<Look_up__c> getLups() {
      return [select name, ID, start_date__c, end_date__c , location__C  from Look_up__c where ID = :TID ];
    }
```

How can I efficiently get a field as a variable on the record to use as a query parameter? thanks!
Also, more generally - on a getRecord(), does one return the ID, or the (whole) record? 
Can't quite understand why I can't use this in my instance if I actually got the record and not just the ID-

```
T = (Custom_object__C) controller.getRecord(); 
         TID = t.Look_up__c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. Query the target object record directly (if you have only one).
2. Create a `Map<Id, SObject>` to hold your target object records.
3. Use a `TYPEOF` query (must be enabled through support).

Take a look at [Understanding Polymorphic Keys and Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys) for a little more information on #3.

---

**Single Record**

Since you only appear to need one record, you can actually just query for it. For instance if you were looking for approvals on a specific `Case` record. If you are writing an extension you can access the `StandardController` in your constructor:

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    List<String> fieldsToQuery = new List<String> { 'Field__c' };
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(fieldsToQuery);
    // above only needed for fields not referenced on the page
    Case record = (Case)controller.getRecord();
}
```

If for some other reason you know there will be a record corresponding to the Id, your query would simply look like:

```
Case record = [SELECT Field__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :targetId];
```

Otherwise, you can query for a list and pull in the record if it's not empty:

```
Case record;
List<Case> candidates = [SELECT Field__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :targetId LIMIT 1];
if (!candidates.isEmpty()) record = candidates[0];
```

---

**Maps**

If you have multiple target object records, you can use a map.

```
Map<Id, Case> targetRecords = new Map<Id, Case>([
    SELECT Field FROM Case WHERE Id IN :targetIds
]);
```

---

**TYPEOF**

Polymorphic query support must be enabled to use `TYPEOF` queries ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm)), but they are pretty useful for you in this instance once they are enabled.

```
List<ProcessInstanceStep> steps = [
    SELECT StepStatus,  
        TYPEOF ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
            WHEN Case THEN Field__c
        END
    FROM ProcessInstanceStep
    WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Type = 'Case'
];
```

Comment: I only need a single record - the parent of object I am using in the standard  controller in the VF page, the parent of what is returned in my extension instance when I do -- T = (Custom_object__C) controller.getRecord();

Comment: @jaw999 So just make `T` a property (add `{ get; private set; }`) and then reference that instead.

Comment: I need to reference the field on T as the filter in my query and all my methods don't work. where ID =: t.lookup_field__c does nothing. Code compiles but page tells me i never returned that field. SO i guess getRecord doesn't get the record?

Comment: @jaw999 Did you call `addFields` with `Lookup_Field__c`?

Comment: OK, progress. So I have to add fields? It is not intuitive that GetRecord doesn't return the record and its fields. It functions more like getId?

Comment: It gives you all fields that are referenced in your page. Anything on top of that needs to be added to the query manually with `addFields`. See [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107076/sobject-row-was-retrieved-via-soql-without-querying-the-requested-field-opportu/107079#107079) for a bit more depth of explanation.